# Angular When I Update, the Information Disappears

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am writing a code where the user can update some data. When the user saves the information for the first time, information on the screen disappears. And then when I click the editing button for a second time, the editing dialog does not open, and I get the error below. What could be the problem?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a little snippet of the HTML and TS for the editing dialog component:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="40" class="w-100-p pr-8">
                    <mat-label>Receipt Code</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="StockIntegrationCode" type="number">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="40" class="w-100-p pr-8">
                    <mat-label>Receipt Name</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="Name" type="text">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        <button mat-stroked-button class="amber-fg pr-4" (click)="save($event)"> Kaydet</button>
```

TS:

```
save(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.form.valid) {
            this.receipt.Name = this.form.controls["Name"].value;
            this.receipt.ReceiptType.Id = this.form.controls[
                "ReceiptType"
            ].value;
            this.receipt.ReceiptGroupType.Id = this.form.controls["ReceiptGroupType"].value;
            this.receipt.StockIntegrationCode = this.form.controls[
                "StockIntegrationCode"
            ].value;

this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
                "Receipt will be changed, are you sure?";

            this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this._productionService
                        .saveAndGetReceipt(this.receipt)
                        .subscribe((response: IReceipt) => {
                            this.receipt = response;
                            this._messages.Show(
                                "Receipt is updated",
                                "SUCCESS",
                                3
                            );
                            this._dialogRef.close(true);
                        });
                }
            });





setReceiptItems() {
        let receipts: IReceipt[] = [];
        for (let d of this.dataSource2.data) {
            receipts.push(d.Receipt);
        }

        let receiptItems: IReceiptItem[] = [];
        for (let d of this.dataSource1.data) {
            receiptItems.push(d);
        }
        for (let d of this.dataSourceMuadil.data) {
            receiptItems.push(d);
        }

        let receiptTerms: IReceiptTerm[] = [];
        for (let d of this.dataSourceTerm.data) {
            receiptTerms.push(d);
        }

        this.receipt.PackagingReceipts = receipts;
        this.receipt.ReceiptItems = receiptItems;
        this.receipt.ReceiptTerms = receiptTerms;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code where you declare `setReceiptItems` method/setter? The error says that you are trying to add property to a Boolean.

Comment: Now show the part where you declare the `receipt` component member (this.receipt). Also log it to the console before the line `this.receipt.PackagingReceipts = receipts;` you will probably get a Boolean value there instead of what you expect. Beside that, you can replace your loops to `let receipts: IReceipt[] = this.dataSource2.data.map(d=> {return d.Receipt as IReceipt})`

Comment: maybe your problem is with `this._dialogRef.close(true);`  try `this._dialogRef.close(response);` just shooting in the dark

Comment: Thank you, you are right the problem was `this._dialogRef.close(true);`